# select category from ListView and show a class depending on the selected button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview

I am making an e-commerce application and I want to make a category ListView, but I want to filter the products depending on which ListView button is selected, I tried to do it in setState() but it didn't work.

[This is my app with de ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNFSv.png)

[And when selecting another category, I need the information below the ListView to change too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxsZG.png)

This is my home_page() :

```
  class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int activeIndex = 0;
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  final urlImages = [
    'assets/chair.png',
    'assets/table.jpeg',
    'assets/lamp.jpeg',
    'assets/sillon.jpeg'
  ];

  List category = ['Trending now', 'Sofa', 'Table', 'Chair'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

          title: const Text("Home", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          actions: [
            IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.qr_code, color: Colors.black,), onPressed: () {

            },
            ),
            IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.black,), onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const SettingsAppBar()
                  )
              );
            },)
          ],
          leading: IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black,), onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const MenuAppBar()
                )
            );
          },),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Descounts()
                          )
                      );
                    },
                    child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                        options: CarouselOptions(height: 250,
                            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                            autoPlay: true,
                            autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                            onPageChanged: (index, reason){
                              setState(() {
                                activeIndex = index;

                              });
                            }
                        ),
                        itemCount: urlImages.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex){
                          final urlImage = urlImages[index];

                          return buildCard(urlImage, index);
                        }
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 30,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: category.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                            if (category[selectedIndex] == "Trending now"){
                              TrendingNow();
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: index == selectedIndex
                                ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent
                                : Colors.grey.shade400,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            category[index], style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TrendingNow()


                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  Widget buildCard(String urlImage, int index) => Container(
    width: 430,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
    height: 430,
    child: Image.asset(urlImage),

  );
}
```

This is my TrendingNow() class:

```
  class TrendingNow extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrendingNow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TrendingNow> createState() => _TrendingNowState();
}

class _TrendingNowState extends State<TrendingNow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 0.77,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              ProductSection(
                product: furProducts[index],
                press: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailScreen(product: furProducts[index])
                      )
                  );
                },
              ),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: furProducts.length,
          physics: const ScrollPhysics(),),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

what I need is to show different information below the listview depending on which category is selected

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you use the condition for only first (trending) one not for other:

```
onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                            if (category[selectedIndex] == "Trending now"){
                              TrendingNow();
                            }
                          });
                        },
```

replace this code with:

```
onTap: (){
setState((){
selectedIndex = index;
Navigator.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TrendingNow(index: selectedIndex),),);
});
}
```

and in trendingNow page call data according to index